# Question on circle related to chords and arcs

Tags: geometry

In the following figure how do I prove that arc AC +arc BD= arc CB +arc AD=semicircle.Given that chords intersect at $90^o$.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$90^\circ=\angle AOC=\frac{\mathrm{arc}AC+\mathrm{arc}BD}{2}$. Also $90^\circ=\angle COB=\frac{\mathrm{arc}CB+\mathrm{arc}AD}{2}$. Thus the firs part is shown.

On the other hand, since $180^\circ=\mathrm{arc}AC+\mathrm{arc}BD$, thus the sum of this arcs is an arc of a half of circunference. This proves the second part.

Comment: Is first line that you have written is theorem?Plz provide any link of this or add prove here itself.

Comment: http://www.regentsprep.org/regents/math/geometry/gp15/circleangles.htm

Comment: Please explain this.How central angle equal to arc subtending it in circle